# Set tick behavior of swing JSlider and JTextField

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield, jslider

This is my GUI:

[image]

Below is a SSCCE that will produce exactly this. The `JSlider` is connected to the `JTextField` showing values between 0 and 100.

I have set the following to make it stop on intervals of 10. It works, but the textfield will still show values between the 10s (Like 73) when dragging, and then adjust it when i let go of the slider. Is there a way to ONLY show tens, even when dragging?

```
js.setMinorTickSpacing(10);
js.setSnapToTicks(true);
```

SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class SSCCE {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE JSlider + JTextField");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("", "[200!][100!]", ""));

        final JSlider js = new JSlider();
        final JFormattedTextField tf = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance());

        js.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                tf.setText(String.valueOf(js.getValue()));
            }
        });
        tf.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
                String typed = tf.getText();
                js.setValue(0);
                if (!typed.matches("\\d+")) {
                    return;
                }
                int value = Integer.parseInt(typed);
                js.setValue(value);
            }
        });
        js.setMinorTickSpacing(10);
        js.setSnapToTicks(true);

        panel.add(js);
        panel.add(tf, "grow");
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It works, but the textfield will still show values between the 10s
>   (Like 73) when dragging, and then adjust it when i let go of the
>   slider. Is there a way to ONLY show tens, even when dragging?

Simply round off current `JSlider` value to the nearest 10 and than set the `JTextField` to that number:

```
 js.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

                if(js.getValueIsAdjusting()) {//slider value is still being adjusted
                    int num=(int)(Math.rint((double) js.getValue() / 10) * 10);//round to nearest 10
                    tf.setText(String.valueOf(num));//set textfield with value of nearest 10                  
                } else {//slider value has been set/no adjustments happenening
                    tf.setText(String.valueOf(js.getValue()));
                }

            }
        });
```

Also have a read on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), specifically on [`Event Dispatch thread` (EDT)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), which requires us to create and manipulate all Swing components on the EDT via [`SwingUtilities.invokeXXX`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28%29) block:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //create/manipulate UI, components etc here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. However, this doesn't do exactly what i want. It does get rid of showing number between decades, which is good. But I also want the number to change while dragging.

Comment: @Goatcat see updated post hope that helps, note it is coded from head so maybe small syntax errors or compile error if anything

Comment: @Goatcat glad to be of help... See updated post on Swing EDT/concurrency